# I'm sorry, what's your name again? - I told you

Tags: word, cipher

**ggvayofxbqftmphsrighnfsiiiegkugdrexyyvgrdtvyjklxxbpstnsunc**

isvexcioinid (2)(4)
xfviirisit (5) itxhviirld (2)(2)(1)

```
Help me figure out his name!
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

His name is

> Bob

The second line - isvexcioinid (2)(4) xfviirisit (5) itxhviirld (2)(2)(1)
can be broken down as follows

> Take every second letter and you get the words second, first, and third, interspersed with Roman numerals. The numbers at the end tell you where to separate

In detail:

> second/ivxiii (2)(4) gives you iv and xiii (4 and 13), first/xviii(5) gives you 18, and third/ixvil(2)(2)(1) gives you ix, vi and L, or 9, 6, and 50

Then arrange those according to

> The first/second/third, and you get 18 4 13 9 6 50. Take those nth letters from the first line

Which reads

> iambob

Comment: Don't know where you get that name from. Clearly his initials are O.B. and he's a poet writing iambs. **;-)**

Comment: @Randal'Thor - You almost got it. rot13/ Gur vnzo Byq Obl vf Funxrfcrner!